# What does make the score of a voting regressor less than those of its voters?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, regression, ensemble-learning

Regarding ensemble learning, I've frequently heard that ``*Estimators that are more diverse in some sense tend to have better performing ensemble*'' [[tmrlv's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359013/why-do-the-ensemble-learners-do-well-on-regression-classification-tasks)]. To assess this claim, I just took a `DecisionTreeRegressor` and a `Seuqential` model to solve a regression problem based on the voting approach, say, using `VotingRegressor`. As far as I know, decision trees and neural networks are diverse estimators, so I expect my Ensemble model to outperform those voters' performances. Here is a simple test which illustrates otherwise.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import tensorflow as tf
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor

housing = fetch_california_housing()

seed1 = 7
seed2 = 5
seed3 = 42

X_train_full, X_test, y_train_full, y_test = train_test_split(housing.data, housing.target, random_state=seed1)
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train_full, y_train_full, random_state=seed2)

scaler = StandardScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_valid = scaler.fit_transform(X_valid)
X_test = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)

def build_dnn_reg():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, tf.keras.activations.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, tf.keras.activations.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0003),
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MSE])
    return model

dnn_reg = KerasRegressor(build_dnn_reg)

rnd_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=5,
                            min_samples_leaf=1,
                            max_leaf_nodes=9, random_state=seed1)

vot_reg = VotingRegressor(estimators=[("rnd", rnd_reg), ("dnn", dnn_reg)])

rnd_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
dnn_reg.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 90, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
vot_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

rnd_reg_scr = cross_val_score(estimator=rnd_reg, X=X_valid, y=y_valid, cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
vot_reg_scr = cross_val_score(estimator=vot_reg, X=X_valid, y=y_valid, cv=10, n_jobs=-1)

yhat_rnd_reg = rnd_reg.predict(X_test)
yhat_dnn_reg = dnn_reg.predict(X_test)
yhat_vot_reg = vot_reg.predict(X_test)

print("rnd_reg_mse: {0}".format(mean_squared_error(y_test, yhat_rnd_reg)))
print("dnn_reg_mse: {0}".format(mean_squared_error(y_test, yhat_dnn_reg)))
print("vot_reg_mse: {0}".format(mean_squared_error(y_test, yhat_vot_reg)))

print("rnd_reg_scr: {0}".format(vot_reg.score(X_test, y_test)))
print("dnn_reg_scr: {0}".format(vot_reg.score(X_test, y_test)))
print("vot_reg_scr: {0}".format(vot_reg.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

In particular, the code above reports the following metrics.

```
rnd_reg_mse: 0.7501101252790635
dnn_reg_mse: 0.45553422440199703
vot_reg_mse: 0.8858773948030302

rnd_reg_scr: 0.4371867731255331
dnn_reg_scr: 0.6582092706826692
vot_reg_scr: 0.3353195772437395
```

As one observes, the scores of my voting classifier is less than those of the voters'. How can these results be justified?

Answer (score 0):

There are no guarantees in this sort of thing, so I'd first caution that you may well get worse performance in an ensemble, even with "diverse" voters.

One particular peculiarity here though is that your voting ensemble doesn't get to set the fit parameters that you set in your solo keras regressor.  So internally, the keras voter is only fitting one epoch ([the default](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)).  I don't see an easy way to overcome that in `VotingRegressor`, but for comparison's sake you can see how `rnd_reg` performs when fitted with the default.

Comment: Can you explain how you know that the ensemble does not set the parameters of the fit method of the Keras voter?

Comment: In short, that's just how the sklearn API behaves: fit parameters aren't preserved.  But more concretely, split up your code and run the two fits separately: you'll see that when you fit the voting model, there is no validation score printed, and only one epoch.